# How to access Mysql installed on my google cloud instance via Mysql workbench

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I have Mysql installed on google cloud instance and its running fine.
Earlier i had a separate google cloud sql instance ,but due to performance issues i installed mysql on my google cloud instance.Iam currently running the database from my google cloud instance.
The issues is that when it was a seperate sql instance i could access the database from Mysql Workbench.
But now that i have it installed on my google cloud instance,i can not access it from workbench.
Is there a way i can access it from my workbench.
Please advise and help

Comment: What issues are you encountering exactly? What have you tried? Did you assign an IP to your cloud sql instance and tried to connect?

Comment: earlier we had a separate sql instance which had a seperate ip.
But now we have installed sql onto the google cloud instance ,so my vm and sql are both running on the same machine instead of sql instance running seperately and vm running seperately.But since i have installed sql on the vm now i can not access it from mysql workbench software.Earlier when sql instance was separate i could access it via mysql workbench.Is there something i need to do now to access sql using work bench?why am i not able to access it now using workbench

Comment: So you are running MySQL on a Compute Engine VM, right? you should make sure that the MySQL port (normally `3306`) is accesible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created user in the cloud MySQL instance by giving current public IP. Once you done with it go to the MySQL workbench and click on little plus icon. Then you get a window like below. You can give any name to the database. For the host name you must provide host address relevant to your MySQL instance. Once you done with give a username. To enter the password you must click on the **Store in Vault** enter it. Once you complete click on **TestConnection**. If it gives successful message then your connection is done. If not you must recheck inputs most input your public IP, because sometimes this change even after one or two hours. No need of filling **Default Schema** field. This might be helpful for your work.
[image]

Comment: There is one caveat to that, a user created in the instance does not have GRANTS to create things like stored procedures.  I have been pulling my hair out on trying to get any user (even tried AIM) with that role so I can load sProcs.